# How many possible Jordan decompasitions for an Endomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, characteristic-polynomial

Let V be an vector space and $\phi \in End_\mathbb{C}(V)$ a linear map with the characteristic polynomial $P_\phi(X) = (x-2)^3(x-5)^2$. How many possible Jordan normal form are there for $\phi$?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: $$ \left(  \begin{array}{ccccccccc} &?&&?&&0&&?&  \\ 2&&2&&2&&5&&5 \end{array}  \right) $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You should also provide the minimal polynomial that could be one of

- $(x-2)(x-5)$,
- $(x-2)(x-5)^2$,
- $(x-2)^2(x-5)$,
- $(x-2)^2(x-5)^2$,
- $(x-2)^3(x-5)$,
- $(x-2)^3(x-5)^2$.

With that in mind the posibles respectively are

$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
2&0&0&0&0\\
0&2&0&0&0\\
0&0&2&0&0\\
0&0&0&5&0\\
0&0&0&0&5\\
\end{array}
\right]$
,
$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
2&0&0&0&0\\
0&2&0&0&0\\
0&0&2&0&0\\
0&0&0&5&1\\
0&0&0&0&5\\
\end{array}
\right]$
,
$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
2&1&0&0&0\\
0&2&0&0&0\\
0&0&2&0&0\\
0&0&0&5&0\\
0&0&0&0&5\\
\end{array}
\right]$
,

$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
2&1&0&0&0\\
0&2&0&0&0\\
0&0&2&0&0\\
0&0&0&5&1\\
0&0&0&0&5\\
\end{array}
\right]$
,
$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
2&1&0&0&0\\
0&2&1&0&0\\
0&0&2&0&0\\
0&0&0&5&0\\
0&0&0&0&5\\
\end{array}
\right]$
,
$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
2&1&0&0&0\\
0&2&1&0&0\\
0&0&2&0&0\\
0&0&0&5&1\\
0&0&0&0&5\\
\end{array}
\right]$.